# how to read .text file in edge node using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to read a .text file in edge node using Scala.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val srcFile=sc.textFile("file://home//viji.palanisamy//dev//kpi_library//EDI//Prof_test1").toString()
  readFile(srcFile)
}

def readFile(filename: String) = {
  val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(filename)
  println("bufferedSource"+bufferedSource)
}
```

Got an error like file not found. Is there any solution to read text from node using Scala.

Comment: How are you running this program?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any solution to read text from node using Scala.

Unless you want to read file locally, using standard IO tools ([Read entire file in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284423)) and `parallelize` there isn't.

You have to distribute the file to each executor node or place it in a distributed storage.

The trick shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47845360/9658417 by [user8371915](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8371915/user8371915):

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

val filename: String = ???
sc.addFile(filename)

val srcFile=sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get(filename))
```

However if all you want is to read local file on the driver, skip `textFile` part and only:

```
Source.fromFile(filename)
```

Comment: how to iterate over the src file .?

Comment: File file:/data/yarn/nm/usercache/viji.palanisamy/appcache/application_1524383649400_0064/container_1524383649400_0064_01_000001/home/viji.palanisamy/dev/kpi_library/EDI/Prof_test1.txt does not exist

Comment: any solutions ?